# Python poetry, install optional dependencies

Tags: python-packaging, python-poetry

I just want the poetry equivalent of this:

```
$ pip install pydantic[email]
```

I've read all the relevant posts. Now my `pyproject.toml` looks like this (I tried everything else, too):

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
pydantic = {version = "*", optional = true, extras = ["email"]}
...

[tool.poetry.extras]
email = ["pydantic"]
```

I also removed `.venv`, and `poetry.lock`, then `$ poetry install`. No use. The runtime error is clear:

```
ImportError: email-validator is not installed, run `pip install pydantic[email]`
```

I can add one detail: `pydantic` itself is a dependency (it was absent from `pyproject.toml` before I ran into this problem).

Comment: Run `poetry add 'pydantic[email]'` then look at the content of `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: Yes, it's just `pydantic = {extras = ["email"], version = "^1.8.2"}`. And it works. It looks like I tried it too, manually :) . `[tool.poetry.extras]` section is not needed any more?

Comment: The section `[tool.poetry.extras]` in combination with `optional = true` is if your project (library or application) has "_extras_" itself. So in your case, you don't need those.

Comment: Will you create an answer, so I could click on it?

Comment: yeah, this is not a duplicate. your linked post is about providing extras, your question is about consuming them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add something like the following in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
pydantic = {version = "*", extras = ["email"]}
```

and then run:

```
poetry install
```

or directly via this command:

```
poetry add 'pydantic[email]'
```